# Mixed Fragment Types in Tab Listener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tab listener based on the documentation code google provided and the sherlock action bar class.

I was wanting to have two of my tabs to use a ListFragment class and one to use a custom GridFragment class.

However the tab listener will only except one type at a time, would I need to just create a standard fragment and put a list view or grid view in it ? or would I need to create a separate tab listener for each ? or is there a way for a tab listener to except any type of fragment, standard, list or grid as long as it inherits from the fragment class.

```
package com.NYXDigital.LookBunnyFind;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;



public class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private SherlockFragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment)SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes I have managed to solve it. I ended up creating a generic fragment which had basic functions to set the tile of the view pager. Which then my Grid and List Fragment Subclass and customise.

Comment: I know this is coming from me quite late. I am stuck in a similar situation except that in my case I am using a listfragment and a fragment. How did you generalise this tabactivity to support both the types?

Comment: Never too late :) I've posted an  answer below complete with the code I used , let me know if you think I should open source my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a generic fragment item class which the TabListener accepted as its arguments. This class excepts a fragment class and auto-creates it for you.

This code below is the class that will contain each fragment class you want added along with a title. You will need one for each fragment added to the tab listener.

```
package com.NYXDigital.LookBunnyFind.Widget;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentViewPagerItem {
    private String title;
    private Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass;

    public FragmentViewPagerItem(String title, Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass){
        this.title = title;
        this.setFragmentClass(fragmentClass);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Class<? extends Fragment> getFragmentClass() {
        return fragmentClass;
    }

    public void setFragmentClass(Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
    }

    public Fragment newInstanceOfFragmentClass() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        return this.fragmentClass.newInstance();
    }

}
```

This the adapter modified to accept an array of the FragmentViewPagerItemClass Above

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.NYXDigital.LookBunnyFind.Widget.FragmentViewPagerItem;

public class FragmentViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<FragmentViewPagerItem> mFragments = new ArrayList<FragmentViewPagerItem>();

    public FragmentViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(FragmentViewPagerItem fragment) {
        if (mFragments == null) {
            mFragments = new ArrayList<FragmentViewPagerItem>();
        }
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        try {
            fragment = mFragments.get(position % mFragments.size())
                    .newInstanceOfFragmentClass();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position % mFragments.size()).getTitle()
                .toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

So in order to use these classes you would need to create a FragmentViewPagerItem for each Fragment and pass in a title as well as the class for your fragment. Then add it to the adapter using the addFragment method, like you would normally. Then set it as the ViewPager's Adapter and bind the title indicator to see the titles.

```
// Create adapter for pager and add fragments to be displayed
FragmentViewPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentViewPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());

// Local
FragmentViewPagerItem localFragment = new FragmentViewPagerItem(
        "Local", BranchListFragment.class);
adapter.addFragment(localFragment);

// Find
FragmentViewPagerItem findFragment = new FragmentViewPagerItem("Find",
        FindFragment.class);
adapter.addFragment(findFragment);

// Events
FragmentViewPagerItem eventsFragment = new FragmentViewPagerItem(
        "Events", EventListFragment.class);
adapter.addFragment(eventsFragment);

// Set the pager with an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

// Bind the title indicator to the adapter
TabPageIndicator mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

I'm thinking of open sourcing this, what do you guys think ?